# Trouble transitioning images between active sections

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a virtual tour which involves the user clicking arrow images depending on the location they wish to go, which will then display a new image of the corresponding location. I would like to gradually transition between the images when the user clicks, however I'm having trouble doing so within this particular context. These are the basics of what I have in my HTML:

```
<div id="tour_images" class="pics">
            <section id="beginning">
                <div class ="arrow">
                    <a href="#two">
                        <img src="turnRight.png" alt="Right Arrow"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <img src="imgs/beginning.jpg" />
            </section>​
            <section id="two">
                <div class="arrow">
                    <a href="#three">
                        <img src="turnRight.png" alt="Right Arrow"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src ="imgs/two.jpg" />
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="three">
                <div class="arrow">
                    <a href="#four">
                        <img src="turnRight.png" alt="Right Arrow"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src ="imgs/three.jpg" />
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="four">
                <div class="arrow">
                    <a href ="#beginning">
                        <img src="turnRight.png" alt="Right Arrow"/>
                    </a>
                    <div>
                        <img src ="imgs/four.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </section>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
section {
    display:none; 
} 

section:target{ 
    display:block;
}

section img {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 500ms opacity;
}

section:target img {
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

As expected, the targeted sections display on click, however the transition of the images on-click isn't working (rather the images just immediately pop up). Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

UPDATE: I've managed to come up with a solution on this which involves changing the CSS to the following (note there is a button at the beginning that, once clicked, displays the first section):

```
section {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    -khtml-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

section:target{ 
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser and its version you might have to include specific rules:

```
section img {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 500ms opacity;
    -o-transition: 500ms opacity;
    -ms-transition: 500ms opacity;
    -moz-transition: 500ms opacity;
    -khtml-transition: 500ms opacity;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms opacity;
}
```

Yes, that is annoying, but sometimes required.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added this to the CSS, but unfortunately still no luck in either Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Then I suggest you use the development console of the browsers and check if the rules get applied to the element at all.

Comment: Em, I just realize that I have troubles understanding your rules at all: what does `:target` mean in there?

Comment: `:target` is used for displaying the current section only.

Comment: Yeah, just realized myself. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, not sure, but this might actually be issue here: unlike with other selectors like classes and the like the content is not modifed whilst being present. Instead for the browser calling the same url with a different target part in the url is like loading a new page. If so (not sure currently), then a transition cannot catch, since there is no modification to apply the transition to. UPDATE: No, actually it looks like this is perfectly possible, as long as the targets are selected within the page itself.

Comment: There is a nesting error inside your html markup in the last `<section>`: the `div`s are unbalanced.

Comment: Thanks for that catch, I've fixed the nesting issue. I've been looking into the development console, and as far as I can tell, the rules aren't getting applied for some reason.

Comment: Actually your css code _does_ work. I created a fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/8yzx9qos/ Obviously I have no idea about the real layout, but you can see the transition getting applied... This might be a conflict with the `display: none;` rule which I commented out. I did so because otherwise I cannot see the anchors, so there is nothing to click. How is that navigation meant to work?!?

Comment: The purpose of the `display: none;` rule is to only display the targeted sections on the page (so, ideally, only the current image will be displayed). I still need to figure out how this will be accomplished while still displaying the first location, but I don't want to take this too off topic. I commented out the `display: none;` and that does indeed do the trick, however introduces a new set of problems in that images I don't want displayed are now displayed. It could just be that my entire navigational structure is wonky and I should look into taking a different approach.